# Haskell: Find two related elements in a list

Tags: list, haskell

I am new to Haskell/FP. I want to solve this task:

This list is given: [1721, 979, 366, 299, 675, 1456]

Find the two elements that sum to `2020` and multiply them. The solution is 1721 * 299.

I think in Haskell, the tools I can use to solve this problem are list comprehension and fold (or a combination of them). But I don't understand how I can write a list comprehension that takes into account other elements of the same list, and not just one element at the time.

This is what I came up with after several hours (`ints` is the list):

```hs
print [(x,y, x*y) | x <- ints, y <- ints, x+y == 2020]
```

It actually prints the right answer. But I think my solution is dirty:

- I feed the input list twice into the list comprehension. Is this correct? It seems like overhead/duplication to me. I am sure there is a better way.
- The return of the function is a list with two same entities (I assume this is because of what I described in the last bullet): `[(1721,608,514579),(1721,608,514579)]` - of course I could get a single element with `head`, but that doesn't solve the root of the problem.

Comment: Wel you will enumerate over every two combinations, so this will use *quadratic time*. By sorting the list first, you can obtain linear time.

Comment: You will get each answer twice because `x` and `y` can be swapped and `x + y == y+x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this will emit the same value twice is because you have two iterators over the list. This thus means that at some point `x` will take as value 1721 and `y` will take as value 299; but later in the program the opposite will be true: `x` will take 299; and `y` will take 1721.

We can easily fix that problem by using [**`tails :: [a] -> [[a]]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:tails):

```
import Data.List(tails)

[(x,y, x*y) | (x:ys) <- tails ints, y <- ys, x+y == 2020]
```

here for each suffix of `ints`, we will take `x` as the first element, and `ys` as the remaining elements, and then we enumerate over `ys`.

But this still takes quadratic time. This kan be done on *O(n log n)* by sorting the list, and then use recurse where we enumerate over both ends of the list until we find a value equal to 2020. Another option is to make use of a collection like a [**`HashSet`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers-0.2.13.0/docs/Data-HashSet.html#t:HashSet). Then we first store the elements in the `HashSet`, and then for each element `x` in the list, we check if `2020 - x` is in the `HashSet`. I leave these as an execise.

Comment: The `<` in `y <- ys` needs escaped.

Comment: Thanks a lot Willem, and thanks for the bonus exercise. I understand why it emits the result two times. 



I understand the idea, but the syntax is still very confusing to me. I'm confused by the `(x:ys)`. But I think that this is simply due to my lack of understanding of Haskell. I hope that in a few days I will understand such constructs more easily. 

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @AndreasFröwis: that's fixed now.

Comment: Is there any way to fix this without using libraries?

Comment: @SashiniHettiarachchi: this is the `base` package, hence the builtin library.